# Android - How does uiThread block executes?

Tags: android, asynchronous, kotlin, ui-thread

```
doAsync {
    doSomethingAsync()
    uiThread {
        doSomethingUiThread()
    }
}
```

Based on the code above. I understand that `doAsync` creates a thread and executes the code inside its block in that new thread. Also, that `uiThread` executes its block code in the main UI thread. But how does the code execute in a thread that already exists? I mean the UI thread is already executing code (e.g. receiving input events, creating new activities, etc.), so how is the code executed? It just stops all other UI thread code, execute itself and then return to the other code? Or something like that? Please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I heard that `RunOnUiThread` method posts a `runnable`( the {} block in kotlin)  to the `handler` of the UI thread. Then the UI thread will execute the `runnable.run()` method when it is not busy. As you know there **must be** a time when the UI thread us not busy, because it will cause the system to show ANR(applicafion not responding) message if not (And even it throws`Exception`s when the UI thread tries to run time-consuming(lagging) jobs like networking :)).

**edit **
Here's a java code that shows you how `runOnUiThread` works.
Cited from [this blog (Korean)](https://blog.yatopark.net/%EC%95%88%EB%93%9C%EB%A1%9C%EC%9D%B4%EB%93%9C-ui-thread-%EC%82%AC%EC%9A%A9%EB%B2%95-handler-runonuithread-view-post/)

```
@Override
public final void runOnUiThread(Runnable action)
{
    if (Thread.currentThread() !=mUiThread)
    {
        mHandler.post(action);
    }
    else
    {
        action.run();
    }
}
```

P.S. I am not an export in kotlin, but I hope my answer helped you.

Comment: So it just executes as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

It posts a message to the looper on the ui thread, passing it a Runnable with the code in your runOnUiThread block